# Why was my flag declined?

Tags: support

[Comment in question:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294243/is-there-a-downside-to-going-multiple-days-without-sleeping#comment415647_294243)

> Hot Network Questions, here we come...

The comment is a Facebooky-comment at best. It is not constructive to the question, has no relevance to the question's contents, yet I've flagged this several times to be removed only to be rejected every single time.

If you declined my flag, could you at least help me understand what about this comment makes it so useful to the question?

Comment: While I wouldn't call it facebooky, its not constructive and is too chatty. I saw comments get removed for less. I think that it can stay, as long as no one minds it, but apparently it bothers some people (for example you).

Comment: Related: [Hot Network Question Silly Title Comment Sanity](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9956/4797)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**IT WAS MEEEE**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a43kowi2ncI) (well, for *one* of the declines at least).

First, I think it's important to note that there were 4 extra comments there all boiling down to *"Omg dis title"* or variations thereof, which I deleted as per your other 4 flags:

[image: Deleted Comments]

I agree that most of these sorts of comments aren't needed, (which is why I deleted the other 4 and only declined that one. But why keep one around? Well, two main reasons:

#### 1. A complete comment purge was unnecessary

Sure, when we're reaching epic proportions of off-topic comments, it's worth it to purge them all, as per this meta:

> Misleading question titles are great. They're kind of a thing around here and that's also great. What's not so great is every time one comes along, and we get dozens of comments about LOL, how amusing the title is...
>
> Usually one or two is kinda okay, but recently every misleadingly titled question has attracted so many of these comments that the decision has increasingly been to remove them all.
>  <sub>- [Hot Network Question Silly Title Comment Sanity](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9956/28182)</sub>

I didn't think 5 comments deserved a complete purge. Especially since we **also** had an on-topic comment, as well as your comment warning others not to post more.

So instead I deleted the four that were just responses to, (or repeating the sentiment of) the first. If we purged all comments it will probably still attract more, leading to more flags and therefore more work.

#### 2. It's harmless, and acts as a signpost for others to upvote

It's a funny-worded question, on a recently-released game, attracting lots of views, and therefore has become a Hot Network Question. It's good for growth (attracting new users to the site) and helps to give a sense of what Arqade's community is like: hilarious and fun (well, mostly).

So I figured:

- It shows that yes, we're aware of the funny ha-ha title.
  <sub>ARQADE IS FUN SEE?!? WE DON'T GET HUNG UP ON SILLY THINGS LIKE COMMENTS!!11!!</sub>
- Combined with your comment asking for no more, it's kinda like saying *"Upvote this instead of re-commenting"*

You did the right thing in flagging them*, let's make that clear. But (in my opinion) having one stick around isn't the end of the world.

---

* One thing that would help in future is if you see these kinds of comments, to flag the question (or answer) for mod attention, rather than the individual comments. Especially so if there are a lot of them - and **even more especially** if you've already gotten a decline on a comment-flag). We can't write a response to comment flags (leading to confusion and metas such as these).

Plus it saves you time flagging, it saves us time handling them, and it allows us to mark the flag helpful whilst not blanket-deleting everything